# Windows Authentication in Windows App

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, visual-studio-2012, logging

I have a stand alone Windows app.  I want to bring Windows Authentication into the app for logging purposes.  I can't find anything on the web about how to do that.  Or something similar.  The app was written in C# VS2012.

Comment: Do you just need to know the current running user or do you need more than that?

Comment: From Tiago Huezo (not enough rep to comment) : do you want to implement the c# code for windows authentication of a windows form application?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to log the information, then getting the current user running the app should be enough.  To get the current user you can use the [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which returns a [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a `Name` property:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  This app currently has a login screen.  I was wanting to eliminate that login if possible.  Some users have permission to use this app and some don't.